# What's the correct way to make before_validation, etc. work in an ActiveModel

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activemodel

Should I extend or include `ActiveModel:Validations:Callbacks:ClassMethods` or `ActiveModel:Validations:Callbacks`?

Answer (score 23):

I got it to work like this:

```
class Foo
  extend ActiveModel::Callbacks
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  include ActiveModel::Validations::Callbacks

  before_validation :bar

  def bar
    # callback logic here
  end
end
```

It's important that you have everything in that order.