# Change or update an attribute value during Rails ActiveRecord validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, activerecord, activemodel

**Summary**: I'm trying to alter an attribute's value *within* a custom `ActiveModel::EachValidator` validator. Given the following prototype:

`def validate_each(record, attribute, value)`

trying to set `value = thing` doesn't appear to do anything -- am I missing something? There should be a smart way to do this...

**Detail**: I accept a URL input as part of a site. I don't want to just take the URL and directly validate that it returns a `200 OK` message, because that would ignore entries that didn't start with `http`, or left out the leading `www`, etc. I have some custom logic to deal with those errors and follow redirects. Thus, I'd like the validation to *succeed* if a user types in `example.org/article` rather than `http://www.example.org/article`. The logic works properly inside the validation, but the problem is that if somebody types in the former, the stored value in the database is in the "wrong" form rather than the nicely updated one. Can I change the entry during validation to a more canonical form?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should leave the validation to do just that: **validate**; it's not the right place to manipulate your model's attributes.

See ActiveModel's **[before_validation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/Callbacks/ClassMethods/before_validation)** callback. This is a more appropriate place to be manipulating model attributes in preparation for validation.

It looks like you have to tell your ActiveModel implementation about callbacks, at least according to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8936906/whats-the-correct-way-to-make-before-validation-etc-work-in-an-activemodel).

```
class YourModel
  extend ActiveModel::Callbacks
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  include ActiveModel::Validations::Callbacks

  before_validation :manipulate_attributes

  def manipulate_attributes
    # Your manipulation here.
  end
end
```

Comment: Good call -- don't try to change things during validation. Adding some code into before_validation helps out, thanks!